# What's the max speed that humans could run?

Tags: human-biology, theoretical-biology, muscles

Assuming humans could use all of their muscle strength at once, with no need of cooling or energy, how fast could we theoretically run?

Comment: This is without current human limits of how much muscle you can use at once.

Comment: Exactly what do you mean with "*limits on how much muscle you can use at once*"? An organism is an integrated whole with different functions, and single muscles cannot be viewed in isolation. Also, running at top speed is not something that is achieved instantaneously, but is a process and a sequence of events, and is dependent on e.g. ATP and anaerobic glycogen use during start and acceleration.